# Как использовать реактивность в плагине LiquorTree?

Tags: vue.js

Вот [дока на плагин](https://amsik.github.io/liquor-tree/#Node-API)
Вот [пример из этой же доки](https://jsfiddle.net/amsik/cuseo1j7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=cuseo1j7)
Из которой следует, что можно обрабатывать события через
@node:checked=""
@node:unchecked=""

Однако если я использую вызов метода в checked - он не сразу видит изменения в v-model

Например:

```
<template>
    <div>        
        <tree
            :data="categories_tree"
            :options="options"
            ref="tree"

            v-model="selected"
            @node:checked="checkChecked"
            @node:unchecked="checkChecked"
        />

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "category-selection",

        props: ['categories_tree'],

        data() {
            return {                
                selected: null,                          
                options: {
                    checkbox: true,
                }
            }
        },

        mounted() {
        },
        methods: {
            checkChecked(){
                if(this.selected.checked.length > 0){
                    console.log(this.selected.checked[0]['id'])
                }

            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

метод checkChecked выводит ID через раз.
если смотреть в консоли в отладчик Vue в модели selected данные меняются, но видимо они меняются позже, чем отрабатывает @node:checked, потому я их не могу отловить.

Кто-то работал с этим плагином и может натолкнуть на мысль?

Comment: можно изменить параметр и событие, на которые будет реагировать `v-model` - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#model  - может это поможет

Comment: @Дмытрык дело в том, что плагин, после инициализации, сразу же возвращает объект собственной структуры, которая передает данные по selected и checked. вот так выглядит https://imgur.com/tSUChrm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взял пример по ссылке, которую Вы указали в вопросе. Добавил `watch` на переменную, в которой хранятся данные. Теперь при любом изменении - данные выводятся в консоль. Вы этого хотели?

```js
var data = [
 [
    { "text": "Who Should Read This Book?" },
    { "text": "How to Read This Book" },
    { "text": "What’s in This Book?" },
    { "text": "Have Fun!" }
  ],
  [
    { "text": "Naming Variables" },
    { "text": "Creating New Variables Using Math", "state": { "disabled": true } },
    { "text": "Incrementing and Decrementing" },
    { "text": "+= (plus-equals) and –= (minus-equals)" }
  ],
  [
    { "text": "Interactive Programming" },
    { "text": "Find the Buried Treasure!", "state": { "disabled": true, "expanded": true }, "children": [
      { "text": "#1: A Snowman-Drawing Function" },
      { "text": "#2: Drawing an Array of Points" },
      { "text": "#3: Painting with Your Mouse" },
      { "text": "#4: Drawing the Man in Hangman" }
    ]},
    { "text": "Object-Oriented Programming" }
  ]


]

     const eventsList = [
        { name: 'tree:mounted', args: ['Tree Component'] },
        { name: 'tree:filtered', args: ['Matches', 'Filter String'] },
        { name: 'tree:data:fetch', args: ['Parent Node'] },
        { name: 'tree:data:received', args: ['Parent Node'] },

        { name: 'node:clicked', args: ['Node']},
        { name: 'node:disabled', args: ['Node']},
        { name: 'node:enabled', args: ['Node']},
        { name: 'node:shown', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:hidden', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:dblclick', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:selected', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:unselected', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:checked', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:unchecked', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:expanded', args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:collapsed',  args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:added',  args: ['Node', 'New Node'] },
        { name: 'node:removed',  args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:text:changed', args: ['Node', 'New Text', 'Old Text']},

        { name: 'node:editing:start',  args: ['Node'] },
        { name: 'node:editing:stop',  args: ['Node', 'isTextChanged'] },
      ]

      let key = 0

      new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data: () => ({
          events: [],
          data: getData(),
          filter: null,
          selected: null,
          opts: {
            fetchData: (node) => {
             return Promise.resolve(data[node.id - 1])
            },
            checkbox: true
          }
        }),

        filters: {
          time(time) {
            return +time
          }
        },

        computed: {
          eventsList() {
            return this.events.concat().reverse()
          }
        },
        watch: {
          selected: function(e){
            console.log(e)
            }
        },
        methods: {
          editNode(node, e) {
            node.startEditing()
          },

          removeNode(node) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
              node.remove()
            }
          },

          addChildNode(node) {
            if (node.enabled()) {
             node.append('New Node')
            }
          },

          initEventViewer(event) {
            const events = this.events

            return function (node, newNode) {
              let nodeText = '-'
              let targetNode = newNode && newNode.text ? newNode : node

              if (targetNode && targetNode.text) {
                nodeText = targetNode.text
              }

              events.push(
                Object.assign(
                  {},
                  event,
                  { time: new Date, nodeText, id: key++ }
                )
              )

            }
          }
        }
      })

      function getData() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(_ => {
            resolve([
              {
                "text": "Introduction",
                "isBatch": true,
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "text": "Part I: Fundamentals",
                "isBatch": true,
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "text": "Data Types and Variables",
                "isBatch": true,
                "id": 3
              }
            ])
          }, 100)
        })
      }
```

```css
.demo-tree {
  width: 50%;
}

.filter-field {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
}

.events-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.events-table-header {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.events-table .event:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.events-table .event {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
}

.events-table .event > span,
.events-table-header > span {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .8s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.node-controls a {
  color: #ff14ce
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/liquor-tree"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="examples">
        <div class="example">
          <div class="example-description">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type to filter..." v-model="filter" class="filter-field">
          </div>
          <div class="example-tree">
            <tree :data="data" :options="opts" :filter="filter" ref="tree" @node:checked="" v-model="selected">
              <div slot-scope="{ node }" class="node-container">
                <div class="node-text">{{ node.text }}</div>
                <div class="node-controls">
                  <a href="#" @mouseup.stop="editNode(node)">Edit</a>
                  <a href="#" @mouseup.stop="removeNode(node)">Remove</a>
                  <a href="#" @mouseup.stop="addChildNode(node)">Add child</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </tree>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="example">
          <div class="example-description">
            List of tree events. Open console to details.
          </div>

          <div class="events-table">
            <div class="events-table-header">
              <span>Event Name</span>
              <span>Event Args</span>
              <span>Node Name</span>
              <span>Timestamp</span>
            </div>

            <transition-group name="fade" tag="div" class="events-table-body">
              <div :key="e.id" v-for="e in eventsList" class="event">
                <span><b>{{ e.name }}</b></span>
                <span>{{ e.args }}</span>
                <span>{{ e.nodeText }}</span>
                <span>{{ e.time | time }}</span>
              </div>
            </transition-group>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Да. Спасибо! Думал обойдусь готовыми событиями. Оказалось нужно смотреть в watch.

Comment: Не за что. Галочка о принятии ответа, находится вверху, слева)

Comment: а я по привычке апвот жму))